# In LightSwitch, how to fill choice list of query parameter from a table

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

In VS LightSwitch, queries can have parameters. When creating a screen, the query parameters are shown on the screen. A choice list can be defined, in which case the field appears as a drop-down-list on the screen.

Instead of defining a static choice list, how can I read the choice list from a table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the answer to my question here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/c69f23bd-4ccb-4bbf-847f-dc01e0baef07

> No, a choice list is a static list of data.  If you want a dynamic list of data, you should create a table and add a relationship to it from wherever you need it.  That will allow you to dynamically filter it through queries, for example.