# How to populate an AutoCompleteBox filter with distinct values from one property?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-lightswitch

My table has a Date field, from which I would like to query all distinct years, and use those years in my ACB screen filter for that same table.

I am trying to figure out the Linq code I need for this. I just need the query to return something like:

2012

2011

2010

and use these values as the Choice List for my Auto Complete Box.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that you can do what you want is by creating a custom RIA service, then adding it as a data source. It may seems daunting the first time, but it's really very easy.

This link will explain the basics. then you can use the LINQ syntax that Kyle showed in his answer.

[How Do I: Display a Chart Built On Aggregated Data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2011/04/08/how-do-i-display-a-chart-built-on-aggregated-data-eric-erhardt.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Yann. I guess for the question if have, the solution you are suggesting is a bit too far fetched... Too complex for a high level developer who is used to simple SQL Server ;). I gave up after a couple of hours, not exactly understanding what I am doing...

Comment: Yeah, it really depends on how necessary the query is. Are you saying that you found that article too hard to follow? I know it looks complicated, but it's really only two simple classes & one linked file. The hardest part is really what you do *in* the RIA service, not creating the service itself. You can also use a RIA service to execute a stored procedure (Eric has an article for that as well), but of course you still need to create a RIA service.

Comment: Just need some more time to figure this out (I will). Maybe this specific query isn't that necessary, but I tend to use a lot of these self-populating drop down lists. Probably due to my pre-millenium Lotus Notes background...

Comment: Yeah, you defiitely have to "relearn" how to do some things with LightSwitch, if you have experience with other programs. It does an incredibale amount of work for you, but it also requires some things to be done in a specific way. Once you get used to it, it'll just be second nature.

Answer (score 2):

If your Date field never contains null, this query will do on EF:

```
    var years = (from row in ctx.YourTable
                 select row.DateField.Year).Distinct().AsEnumerable().Select(e => e.ToString());
```

This returns an IEnumerable< string > but add .ToList() or ToArray() at the end if it suits to you.

And for the completness, if your Date field is nullable, you should filter out null values:

```
    var years = (from row in ctx.YourTable
                 where row.DateField != null
                 select row.DateField.Value.Year).Distinct().AsEnumerable().Select(e => e.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't programmatically set the Choice List of an AutoCompleteBox. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064263/in-lightswitch-how-to-fill-choice-list-of-query-parameter-from-a-table).

However you can use LINQ in the `_PreprocessQuery` method. Create an empty query using Query Designer, click the down arrow next to "Write Code" and choose the `_PreprocessQuery` method. Then use @xeondev's LINQ code like this:

```
partial void Query1_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<TableName> query)
{
    query = (from row in query
             where row.DateField != null
             select row.DateField.Value.Year).Distinct().AsEnumerable().Select(e => e.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Kyle, although your LINQ query is valid, that won't work in LightSwitch, you can't change the "shape" of a query's entity in the *PreProcessQuery* method, you can only restrict the records returned that it returns.

Comment: @YannDuran I was merely commenting on _where_ the LINQ query should go. The actual query I took from xeondev and I didn't look closely at it. I see that you're right about changing the shape. But wouldn't changing the last line to just `select row).Distinct()` and then changing the Summary Property of the table to the Date column so that the date is what appears in the ACB, work? Or am I missing something there as well?

Comment: Kyle, thanks for your suggestion (I do get a single column just showing the years), but the query still returns all years (duplicates)...

Comment: @Maarten Ahh...now I see what Yann sees. xeondev's query will get you the list that you want (i.e. a list of unique years). But you can't assign that to an ACB in normal code (I'm actually working on something similar and coming up short [see here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/25cc79c9-f091-48ea-8619-240ac977e3f4) ) and you can't set that to an ACB in `_PreprocessQuery` because of what Yann said above. My suggestion of `select.row).Distinct()` will return duplicates because of data in the other columns. I think Yann's right, an RIA Service may be it.

Comment: @Maarten You might possibly be able to achieve what you want using `DistinctBy` as mentioned by Jon Skeet in his answer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998066/linq-distinct-values). But I've never used it so I'm not sure.

Comment: From memory Distinct doesn't work for queries in LightSwitch, because the entire entity is returned in the query, so the ID alone will make the record unique.